# Turn on HotSpot via ADB -- Sony Ericsson Xperia mini ST15i

Tags: adb, 2.3-gingerbread, wifi-hotspot

How to turn on wifi hotspot on ST15i via ADB? There is already on post about this using keyevents but it does not work for me. It has hot broken touchscreen, back is always clicking, but before, I turned on USB debugging so ADB works. It is not rooted. I want to use it as mobile hotspot from SIM. It has Android 2.3 GingerBread.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/system/bin/hostapd -e /data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf
```

Comment: Explaining how this is going to help OP makes sense and adds value. In the present form, it is vague